# str.replace not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently writing a function to check if a url param is in the url.  If it is there I am removing it and if it is not yet there I will be adding it.  Essentially toggling the param on button click.  Here is what I have so far.

```
     var value1 = $(this).attr("value");
     var collectionUrl = window.location.href; 
      if (collectionUrl.includes($(this).attr("value")))  {
          console.log("removing:   "  + $(this).attr("value"));
          collectionUrl.replace(value1,"");
      }
      else {
          console.log("adding:   "  + $(this).attr("value"));
          collectionUrl = collectionUrl + $(this).attr("value")+"/";
        }
    ajaxLoadPage(collectionUrl);
```

When the value is absent the value is added the the url as expected.  When the value is already present in the url,  the if statement does work and it outputs "removing:  " value

However the value in the url is not being removed.  I feel like I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `"abc".replace("b","D")` does not change the "abc" but returns new string "aDc" so you need to store the result in your `collectionUrl`.

So call it like this `collectionUrl = collectionUrl.replace(value1,"");`

Comment: ... And `.replace` replaces only the first occurence of the searched sub-string.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thats true if the search expression is a string, if its a `RegExp` it can replace all if the `'g'` flag is enabled.